# Importing a large CSV from Cloud Storage into App Engine Datastore

Tags: python, csv, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datastore

I have a large CSV file, on the order of 1 GB big, and want to create entities into the datastore, one entity per row.

That CSV file is currently residing in Google Cloud Storage. Is there a clean way to do this? All the examples I can find online seem to rely on having the CSV file locally, or don't look like they would scale very well. Ideally there's a streaming API that lets me read in small enough pieces from Cloud Storage to make update calls to the Datastore, but I haven't been able to find anything like that.

Answer (score 2):

The buffer you receive when you open a GCS file is a streaming buffer, which can be pickled. But GCS does not support the iterator protocol to read lines of the CSV. You have to [write your own wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17841468/how-to-open-and-process-csv-file-stored-in-google-cloud-storage-using-python). Like:

```
with gcs.open('/app_default_bucket/csv/example.csv', 'r') as f:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(iter(f.readline, ''))
        for row in csv_reader:
            logging.info(' - '.join(row))
```

If you are familiair with the blobstore you can use it to read large CSV's from GCS using  `blobstore.create_gs_key( "/gs" + <gcs_file_name_here>)`. 
Example [here](http://thedeveloperworldisyours.com/python/gae-reading-big-csv-blobstore-python/)

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is going to be a mapreduce job using the CloudStorageInputReader: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-mapreduce/blob/master/python/src/mapreduce/input_readers.py#L2189

More on mapreduce for python here:  https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-mapreduce/wiki/3-MapReduce-for-Python