# How to read a CSV file in jupyter notebook running on Google Cloud using Python? CSV File is present on Google Storage

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook

I did try the suggestions given in the post "[How to open and process CSV file stored in Google Cloud Storage using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17841468/how-to-open-and-process-csv-file-stored-in-google-cloud-storage-using-python)", but it didn't work. It throws an error " No such file or directory". Is there any API that allows python to read files stored on Google Cloud Storage?

Comment: Posting more details, such as your actual code and specifics about where Jupyter is hosted (Google Cloud is a very broad term)  would help the community to assist better. For some tips see
[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If you were able to solve the issue you were having, it would be beneficial to post your solution as an answer to help others. If not, providing the information Adam requested would help in troubleshooting this further.